# How To Add The '&' Symbol in Variables?

Tags: batch-file

I want to make something like this

```
set ac=&Hello
```

But it will say 'Hello' is not a command. I tried putting double quote like this,

```
set ac="&Hello"
```

But it will show the double quotes. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: How about `set "ac=&Hello"`, and then output with delayed expansion?

Comment: @RajaEzzy Read the answer on [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) which explains in detail how to assign a value to an environment variable right and why the syntax `set "variable=value"` should be used nearly always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `delayedExpansion`, one can `echo` out any content, even special characters without escaping. Take a look at the follow example:

## Longer but Clearer Solution

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "ac=&Hello"
echo !ac!
```

This will output `&Hello` as you expected. There are still some other methods, but this one is one of the simplest one.

---

## Shorter but Messier Solution

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "ac=&Hello"&&echo !ac!
```

Simillar to the above, this snippet only moves the `echo` to the same line as the `set` statement. This will be easier to see when `echo`ing a large content of text.

---

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```
@echo off
set ab=^^^&hello
echo %ab% & pause
```